# Angular Expressions Missing in Dynamically Generated Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having problems with a dynamically generated directive (using a function) and angular expressions being filtered out in the final markup ending up on the screen. I've created a [JSFiddle displaying the problem here](http://jsfiddle.net/EM9wv/4/).

I am generating the template dynamically because we needed a way to generate the markup based on the attributes inside the element.

Basically when defining an expression like so:

```
angular.module('ui.directives', []).directive('uiBar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: function(element, attrs) {
            console.log('hello');
            return '<div>lol: {{ user }}</div>';
        }
    };
});
```

And place it into the body like so:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <ui-bar>I should change to iambar</ui-bar>
</div>
```

The resulting markup is:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope">
    <ui-bar><div class="ng-binding">lol: </div></ui-bar>
</div>
```

The expression is stripped out for some reason. Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Do you need to show the expression `{{ user }}` in the view? If not, you could define `user` in the directive's (or its parent scope) and it will be displayed. It looks like angular silently compiles expression to no value if it can't find the name in the scope (or parent scope) Take a look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/qQPb6/

Comment: Here is another sample that shows it is actually working: http://jsfiddle.net/EM9wv/7/  What is happening is that angularjs has compiled the ng-bind directive that you specified by using `{{ user }}`

Comment: Perhaps Transclude would work with what you want? link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand what you are trying to accomplish with a dynamically generated template. Below is what I would typically do to solve your example.

The HTML would look like this.

```
<ui-bar new-value="hello">I should change</ui-bar>
```

The return statement of the directive would look something like this

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  template: "<div>lol: {{ user }}</div>",

  link: function (scope, element, attrs){
    scope.user = attrs.newValue;
  } // end link
} // end return
```

The above code works in your jsFiddle.

If you could add more information we may be able to give more examples.